# R split function - do not include grouping variable in new dataset

Tags: r, lapply

I usually like to use `lapply()` instead of a `for` loop:

```
lx <- split( x, x$hr) #with the next step being lapply( lx, function( x) ...)).
```

But now each element of `lx` includes the column `hr`, which is inefficient because that information is already in `names( lx)`.

So now I must do:

`lx <- lapply( lx, function( X) select( X, -hr))`

(An alternative is:

```
HR <- unique( x$hr)
lx <- select( lx, -hr)
lx <- split( x, HR)
```

)

The whole point of `lapply()` over a `for` loop is to be efficient so these extra lines bother me.  It seems like such a common use case, and my experience has shown that usually `R` has something more efficient, or I'm missing something.

Can this be achieved in a single function call or one-liner?

EDIT: Specific Example

```
DF <- data.frame( A = 1:2, B = 2:3, C = 3:4)
DF <- split( DF, factor( DF$A))  # but each list element still contains the column A which is
                                 # redundant (because the names() of the list element equals A 
                                 # as well), so I have to write the following line if I want 
                                 # to be efficient especially with large datasets
DF <- lapply( DF, function( x) select( x, -A))  # I hate always writing this line!
```

Comment: OK, I did.  Not sure if there is actually a better solution.  It just seems so common..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the split column first:

```
split(DF[-1], DF[[1]])
```

or

```
split(subset(DF, select = -A), DF$A)
```

**Update:** Added last line.

Comment: So obvious now, of course modifying DF in the first argument doesn't effect the 2nd argument.